# Does Erase Utility for HP Intelligent Provisioning delete also itself

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

After using Erase Utility (HDD and AHS chosen, not RBSU) from HP Intelligent Provisioning in a HP Gen8 blade, I couldn't start the Intelligent Provisioning itself pressing F10 after POST.

Does the Erase also delete all the IP utilities from the server?
Where are the HP Intelligent Provisioning files stored?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Erase Utility does not delete itself. If you are having problems with Intelligent Provisioning, it can be reinstalled according to the instructions on [page 72 here](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c03182305).